# "Cultured in" vs "Cultured at" vs "Cultured about"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice, prepositional-phrases

Do you think we can use the phrases, *cultured in*, *cultured at*, and *cultured about* interchangeably?
I couldn't find any examples of, "cultured," with any of, "in," "at," or "about," in dictionaries. So I would like to ask your opinion. For example, would these sentences be used interchangeably?

> He is cultured in music.

> He is cultured at music.

> He is cultured about music.

Comment: I don't have a specific answer, but this is a weird observation.  What made **cultured in** get so popular in the late 1900s, then suddenly turn around in 1986?  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cultured+in%2Ccultured+at%2Ccultured+about&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccultured%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccultured%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccultured%20about%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccultured%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccultured%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccultured%20about%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I don't think it's syntactically or semantically valid to "particularise" the state of being "cultured" *(characterized by refined taste and manners and good education)* as only being applicable within some restricted domain such as music. So the short answer is *none* of your prepositions work because what you're trying to say isn't something the natives sday in the first place.

Comment: We wouldn't use _any_ of those sentences. _Cultured_ in this sense is a general term for someone who understands and appreciates the arts, music, literature etc., not just a particular one,

Comment: @stangdon: Your NGram might be finding lots of references to (medicinal) bacteria being cultured (grown) in agar-agar, for example.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Maybe you guys wouldn't "particularise" the state of being "cultured", but don't you think any other native speakers do that at all? Wouldn't any of the phrases I gave be used by any native speakers at all?

Comment: Native speakers do not use these phrases because culture isn't though of that way. Feel free to use these phrases, though, and get funny looks. :)

Answer (score 1):

"He is cultured in music" is the only good sentence, although it might sound [outdated](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he%20is%20cultured%20in%22&rlz=1C1CHBF_enSG934SG934&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiks5zl3fXyAhWiH7cAHTlhDt4Q_AUoAXoECAEQCw&biw=1422&bih=677) to some speakers.

Perhaps: "He is cultured when it comes to music", "He is a cultured man, especially on the world of music" or something similar.

Answer (score -1):

Of the phrases you give, "cultured in" is the only one that could make sense to English speakers.

Even then, you should probably not use it.  The meaning of "cultured in music" would be different from "educated in music" or "trained in music", and more like "raised in a family or environment that promoted an appreciation for music".

If that is really what you're trying to say, though, then saying "cultured in music" does not *reliably* communicate that, so you should use more words.